# parallel debugging in visual studio, no standard output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, parallel-processing, output

I'm trying to use the parallel debugger on visual studio 2010 for a project written in C using  MPI. I set it up using instruction I had for setting it up in VS 2008, which I know worked, however when I run I see no output to the screen. Break points are still hit by every process, and I can step through the code and everything appears to process fine, however none of the standard output (ie printf statements) is printing to the screen. Never had this problem with 2008, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.